# Delete class instances in Swift

Tags: model-view-controller, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to fully understand the process of creating class objects in Swift.  Adhering to the idea of MVC, I have the following simple class to represent my data model:

```
// Person.swift

import Foundation

class Person {

    var first: String = "first"
    var last: String = "last"
}
```

In my view controller I have two `IBOutlets` connected to `UITextFields`.  Using the `IBAction` method, I set the `first` and `last` variables with the text from the text fields.

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - IBAction
    @IBAction func addPerson(sender: AnyObject) {

        let peep = Person()
        peep.first = firstName.text
        peep.last = lastName.text
        println("\(peep.first) \(peep.last)")
    }
}
```

Each time the `IBAction` method is called, a new instance of the `Person` class is created.  For my example, I am only interested in the latest `Person` instance.  How do I delete the pervious instance variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to delete them, they are being released for you by the compiler.

You are creating a Person object. Setting some property values and then printing it. After that the object goes out of scope, at which point, as you don't have any other strong references to the object, it will eventually be released.

Have a look at the ARC guide in the Swift Programming Guide for an explanation of the local rules that are applied to object lifetimes an Swift using ARC.